# Best method for threading in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, audiorecord

I have an animation in which triggers an event. This event fires a lot of computing usage and thus stutters the UI.

What I need to do is keep the thread running smoothly. When the event happens it will pass a string down to the thread, perform calculations (including using the audioRecord class) and return a boolean variable.

I have looked around and it seems AsyncTask may be the best solution, but I wanted to see if any of you had any ideas? Considering performance, Is this the best way to go?

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally AsyncTask is fine.
But if you dont need to acess the UI thread for your background operation you can simply use a new thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //do stuff
    }
}).start();
```